# Sphinx sql_attr_multi - how to find exact combination of values?

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I have a working sphinx index of `books` and `categories` (many to many connection)

```
source books : base
{   
    sql_attr_multi =uint categories from query; \
        select book_id, category_id\
        from books\
        join book_categories on book_categories.book_id = books.id
}
```

So, if I use MySQL connection to retrieve records, it would look like this:

```
-- get all books that are in categories 2 and 3 at the same time
SELECT id FROM books WHERE categories = 2 AND categories = 3;
```

This will give me a list of books that are in categories 2 and 3, but also can be in any other category.

[image]

What I want to do is limit results to those **books that are only in categories 2 and 3 and not in any other category**.

[image]

Is that possible, given that a list of all categories is to big to specify it in a `NOT IN ()`?

Comment: Isnt your second venn diagram, showing 2 XOR 3? ie either, but not both. But in the description, is saying AND. So the venn diagram should be the **overlap** between 2 and 3 in blue.

Answer (score 1):

As of sphinx v2.1.2, there is a LENGTH() function, returns the length of the MVA :)

```
SELECT id FROM books WHERE categories = 2 AND categories = 3 AND LENGTH(categories) = 2;
```

Functions dont always work in WHERE, so if above fails could try

```
SELECT id, LENGTH(categories) as len FROM books 
  WHERE categories = 2 AND categories = 3 AND len = 2;
```

(assuming you really do mean AND query. An OR query would be more tricky, but XOR would be easy)